# Equivalence of weak convergence in Sobolev spaces and $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Statement: Let $u_n,u\in W^{k,p}$ where $p\in [1,\infty)$. Then $u_n \rightarrow u$ weakly in $W^{k,p} \Leftrightarrow \partial^s u_n \rightarrow \partial^s u$ weakly in $L^p$ for all $|s|\le k$.

Question. I feel that this statement is true, or at least some variant is. I can prove the $\Rightarrow$ part for $p\in (1,\infty)$, but I'm not so sure about $p=1$ case and the $\Leftarrow$ part. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: View $W^{k,p}$ as a subspace of a product space of $L^p$ spaces. By the Hahn-Banach Theorem it suffices to prove the claim in this product space.

Comment: @deb Thanks for the tip. In that case, the equivalence should also be true for $p=\infty$, right?

Comment: yes, you are right.